# Injecting values into private field in Quarkus test

Tags: java, reflection, mockito, junit5, quarkus

I'm trying to set value to a private field in my test class using FieldSetter in Quarkus Application(Quarkus version: 1.5.2.Final and JDK version:11)

Main Class

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TokenService{
    @Inject @RestClient RestClientInterface client;

    private String someVariable;

    public String someMethod(){}
}
```

Test Class

```
@QuarkusTest
public class TokenServiceTest{
    @Inject TokenService service;
    @InjectMock @RestClient RestClientInterface client;

    @Test
    public void someMethodTest(){
       FieldSetter.setField(service, "someVariable", "someValue");
    }
}
```

But FieldSetter is throwing NoSuchField error. Please help.
Also tried with

```
service.getClass().getdeclaredField("someVariable")
```

But same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to set a private field in a unit test? There may be a legitimate reason, but most probably there is a shortcoming in the design.

Comment: Those private fields in real time workflow are initialized has some expiry time, so I'll be checking if it's still valid or not every time I visit that method. Hence in test case I need to Inject some value to those private fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TokenService` class is `@ApplicationScoped`. This means that if you `@Inject` it somewhere, an instance of the class is *not* injected directly. Instead, what gets injected is so called *client proxy*, which is a *subclass* of the original class. This subclass is responsible for looking up the correct instance on each method invocation (and forwarding the invocation to the instance).

This subclass naturally does *not* declare `someVariable`. That's why `getDeclaredField("someVariable")` fails. I assume `FieldSetter` comes from Mockito -- in which case, it does the same thing and fails for the same reason.

You can either make `TokenService` a `@Singleton` -- in which case there's no client proxy and an instance is injected directly --, or use the knowledge that the client proxy is a subclass and simply look at a superclass. Or -- and that would probably be best -- redesign your code so that you don't have to change `private` fields from outside. That's a code smell anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I have a doubt, how can I initialize 'TokenService' class in my Test class as neither InjectMocks nor  InjectMock annotation is helping

Comment: QuarkusTest doesn't allow us to use Singleton/Dependent scope. It's even mentioned in their blog. `RequestScope` also giving same error.

Comment: Ah, you're right, mockable beans must be normal-scoped. But if you don't need to mock the bean, you can still make it `@Singleton`. Here's how they are different: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#applicationscoped-and-singleton-look-very-similar-which-one-should-i-choose-for-my-quarkus-application However, there's still one crucial thing missing: why do you need to change the `private` field? That is completely unrelated to mocking, or is there a connection?

Comment: Those private fields in real time workflow are initialized has some expiry time, so I'll be checking if it's still valid or not every time I visit that method. Hence in test case I need to Inject some value to those private fields.

Comment: Why not create a test-only method for that? Assuming the test is in the same package as the class, the method can be package-private. I think that's a fairly common thing to do. People often mark such methods with a special-purpose annotation, typically called `@VisibleForTesting`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `@VisibleForTesting` is helpful